# How to reset wasm stdin between calls?

Tags: webassembly, stdio

I have a project which feeds an HTML `<textarea>` as stdin for some wasm code (compiled from C++). Ideally, every call to the wasm should treat this as new data, rather than picking up where it left off. However, I've found that this isn't the case. If I write code to print the first integer it finds on stdin, and type `-1.5` in the textarea, every other run says `5` instead of `-1`. I have looked into this somewhat and documented my findings in [a github issue](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle/issues/4):

> While it's true that the glue code is resetting it properly and the issue is in C, it doesn't always ignore the first however many characters. If you change the number, it always gives the expected output on the first run. It only gives the wrong number on the second consecutive run with the same input.

> I can work around this by adding `while (getchar() != EOF) {}` before the `clearerr` call in the wasm entrypoint, [but] that feels very wrong.

Why is this happening, and how do I prevent it?